# UI thread prevents DLL thread from running

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a C# app that calls into a C DLL. The DLL creates one thread that is time-critical using CreateThread(...,THREAD_PRIORITY_TIME_CRITICAL). The DLL is passed a delegate to callback to inform the app of comm status.
Everything works fine until the UI starts running, for example a mouse click event handler. For as long as the UI event handler is running, the DLL thread stops and only resumes once the event handler exits. Code excerpt below.

SetCallback() is called to set the callback function to DllSetStatus() which prints some value into a RichTextBox "criticalRtb"

DllSetStatus() can be called from either the DLL thread or in response to a call from the C# app (i.e, PrintToRTB() can be called either from the DLL thread or in response to a call to DLL_GetStatus() as shown below)

Once inside *any* managed code event handler, if DllSetStatus() is being executed from the DLL thread, it stops execution until the UI thread exits.

Is there a way to allow the DLL threads to continue execution within the UI?

Things I've tried:

- Setting UI thread priority to lowest
- Inserting Thread.Sleep() in the event handlers

  ```
    public delegate void statusDelegate(int status);                               

    [DllImport(@"CommDLL.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    internal static extern int DLL_SetCallback(statusDelegate fPtr);

    static statusDelegate setStatusDeleg;
    static object rtfLockObj= new object();

    private static bool SetCallback()
    {
        setStatusDeleg = DllSetStatus;
        try { return (DLL_SetCallback(setStatusDeleg) == 0 ? true : false); }
        catch (Exception e) { dllError(e); return false; }
    }

    public static void DllSetStatus(int status)
    {
        if (Monitor.TryEnter(rtfLockObj, -1))
        {
            try { SafeRtbWrite(status); }
            finally { Monitor.Exit(rtfLockObj); }
        }
    }

    private delegate void SafeWriteDelegate(int status);

    public static void SafeRtbWrite(int status)
    {
        if (criticalRtb.InvokeRequired)
        {
            var deleg = new SafeWriteDelegate(SafeRtbWrite);
            criticalRtb.Invoke(deleg, new object[] { status });
        }
        else
        {
            int selStart = criticalRtb.TextLength;
            criticalRtb.DeselectAll();
            criticalRtb.AppendText("Status: " + status);
            criticalRtb.Select(selStart, criticalRtb.TextLength - selStart);
            criticalRtb.SelectionColor = Color.DarkRed;
            criticalRtb.DeselectAll();
        }
    }
  ```

The DLL code is as follows:

```
typedef void(__stdcall * CsSetStatusFunc)(int);
CsSetStatusFunc PrintToRTB = (CsSetStatusFunc)0;
DllExport int __cdecl DLL_SetCallback(CsSetStatusFunc funcPtr)
{
    PrintToRTB = funcPtr;
    return(0);
}

DllExport int __cdecl DLL_GetStatus(void)
{
    PrintToRTB(currStatus);
    return(0);
}

static DWORD WINAPI threadComm(void* param)
{
    (void)param;
    for (;;) 
    {
        portRead();
        if (currStatus != lastStatus)
        {
            PrintToRTB(currStatus);
            lastStatus = currStatus;
        }
        Sleep(0);
    }
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: Start with posting the code.

Comment: what exactly the DLL is doing? is it running something in a non-UI thread? does it need you to pass a thread so it can execute something in it? It's impossible to help with such a limited information

Comment: Anyone knows the answer or sees anything wrong with the above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DLL callback, which it seems posts a message in the App message queue as a result of calling Invoke, is blocked by any UI messages resulting from UI events, so if the Invoke message is posted **after** any UI event message, it will not execute until the UI event is processed first. I'm currently using DoEvents() to consume messages in the queue if the Invoke message is pending.